# executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, crash

I had a project that was working fine.  It had "Core Data" checked, and had the data model all set up. I only started adding a couple entities and properties tonight.  When I try to run my app now, it won't even load.  It just crashes on me.

Here's the error:

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'`

I'm really scared because I don't have a backup of this and if I can't get it working I don't know what I'll do. :)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:
I got fed up with my data, so I just copied a new blank xcdatamodel to my project and I'm going to start fresh.  Thanks for the help!**

Comment: You need to post the relevant portions of the code.

Comment: The code around your executeFetchRequest:error: call would be very helpful in understanding what your issue is.

Comment: You may be fetching the wrong entity from the coredata .. may be a typo at `NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CHECK_HERE" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seemed as if my data got corrupted, so I deleted my data model and the database in the iPhone simulator, and started fresh.

Comment: yeah, don't forget to delete the app from the simulator!

Answer (score 22):

My issue is I didn't use the same name for Entity and Class. Trivial solution to fix it is by giving them the same name.

Comment: is it a trivial solution? You can simply modify Default configuration (mapping: entity -> class) in data model.

Answer (score 21):

If you are using **`MagicalRecored`** with **`Swift`**:

Make sure you use `@objc` directive in the Swift `NSManagedObject` subclass to make the class accessible to Objective-C code from the MagicalRecord library

```
@objc(MyEntity)
class MyEntity: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var myAttribute: Int16
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The entity file will get overwritten anytime you recreate the NSManagedObject subclass though. Is there a better way to do it than manually adding that line each time?

Comment: app crash in iOS 9.3 but working with iOS 10.3
when i add @objc(MyEntity) as suggested it work on iOS 9.3 but app crash on iOS 10.3 any idea why it crash?

Answer (score 14):

After searching all over for a solution, what fixed it for me was doing a Clean/Build in Xcode.

Product->Clean, Product->Build, then try running it.

Comment: I both deleted the app in the Simulator, and did Clean/Build.  Same problem, so this did not fix the issue for me.  I do not want to delete and recreate a complex data model.  So, how to correct the issue non-destructively?

Comment: Why the down-vote, @JayImerman?  I'm sorry that my answer didn't work for you, but that doesn't mean you should down-vote it.  Did you try a "Reset Content and Settings" in the simulator?  Does it work on a real device?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error.

For me, it is because I have added a new Model Version, but I did not set it as "Current Version". Careless me! To fix, select the xcdatamodel, click Design > Data Model > Set Current Version. The xcdatamodel file will then have a green tick.

Hopes that helps.

Answer (score 10):

Also, make sure that your `.xcdatamodeld` file is in the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase of your Build Phases.

Answer (score 9):

Here's what fixed it for me:

As I was converting to Swift 3, Xcode was giving me an error when declaring a new `NSFetchRequest`, saying that it needed a type. After adding the type, I did what anyone else would have assumed; if the request is typed, why specify an entity name? So, I removed it.

It actually was my mistake.

Swift 2.2:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MyEntity")
```

When I first converted to Swift 3:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<MyEntity>()
```

That was giving me an error. I ended up with this:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<MyEntity>(entityName: "MyEntity")
```

And everything works fine. Personally, I'm not sure why it needs to have an entity name specified, if you're typing the request. Maybe they'll update that at some point (I hope)

Comment: Man thank you, you saved my day after searching the whole internet up and down. I wish I could upvote you 100 times! Still a valid solution in 2022 using SwiftUI by the way.

Answer (score 7):

i found this solution in the apple develper forum and it was exactly my problem!

the solutions is that the context must be defined inside the struct App.
not in the environment parameter

```
import SwiftUI
@main
struct CoreDataDemoApp: App {
    
    private let context = CoreDataStack.context. 
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it says Aug 15, 2020

Answer (score 6):

Check if,

- the entity is present in the xcdatamodel file.
- entity name used are same.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Swift 3 and Core Data's new stack syntax:

```
var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyAppModel")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: {
        (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        } else {
            print(storeDescription)
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

Then you should be using this fetch syntax:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Client> = Client.fetchRequest()
```

I had this error on the first fetch after app launches when using different variations:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Client.fetchRequest()

let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Client")
```

Answer (score 2):

I did stumble across the same precise error upon taking my first steps into Core Data (and iOS 11 and Swift 4). I started off a book (sixth edition meant to target Swift 4 but presumably including some legacy stuff).

As suggested in the book my code was:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<ReminderData>()
let entity = ReminderData.entity()
fetchRequest.entity = entity
do {
    let rows = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
} catch {
    fatalError("Unresolved error")
}
```

It turned out that all I got from `ReminderData.entity()` is `nil`. Not sure if I did something wrong when setting up the data model or ... Apple's docs say that `NSManagedObject.entity()` must not be overwritten?

Long story short, the Codegen file `ReminderData+CoreDataProperties.swift` did include the solution:

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ReminderData> {
    return NSFetchRequest<ReminderData>(entityName: "ReminderDB")
}
```

which was all I had to use to end-up with a proper `NSFetchRequest`, no fiddling with the `NSEntityDescription`, problem gone!

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<ReminderData>(entityName: "ReminderDB")
do {
    let rows = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
} catch {
    fatalError("Unresolved error")
}
```

Comment: Or let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ReminderData> = fetchRequest() with no need to type a name of the entity explicitly (by using that function which you mentioned in Codegen file ReminderData+CoreDataProperties.swift)

Answer (score 1):

I built clean, and that didn't fix it. Then I deleted the app, and that didn't fix it. Then I built clean and deleted the app AT THE SAME TIME, and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because this dropdown was not set to "Current Product Module" in the Data Model Inspector in Xcode (13.4.1):

[image: Module dropdown in Data Model Inspector]

Once I set that, it stopped crashing.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the same problem. I copied all my entities. Deleted the data model, recreated an empty one and pasted the entities back into the new data model. Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

First I downloaded the app's data through the Organizer (to see what was happening) and noticed that it offered me to save it under a previous project name.  This puzzled me.  So I exited XCode 4.6.1, deleted the app (and its data) from my iPhone, and came back.

This time I got an error saying `Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model`.  So I looked into the AppDelegate.m file and changed the `URLForResource` in the `- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *) persistentStoreCoodinator` method.  It was set to the name of my app, and I changed it to 'Model' so as to match the name of my Model.xcdatamodeld.
It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was fetching from the wrong database.  My application has 3 sqlite databases, and of course 3 ManagedObjectContext instances.  Well I was submitting the wrong ManagedObjectContext to a method asking it to query a table that didn't exist in the ManagedObjectContext I submitted.  After using the correct ManagedObjectContext, all was good.

Answer (score 0):

I think the original question/problem, and also the issue that most of these answers fixes (just in different ways) is just a real simple one:

Anytime you modify your core data (like adding an entity as you mention), you either have to delete all existing data (if you haven't published your app yet), or add a new version to your model.

Just thought I would post this answer, even though this is an older question, because this answer seems pretty obvious and so far hasn't been discussed in any of the questions or comments I read above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use setter method from CoraData ... Just do something like this...

On your CustomCoreDataManager.m

import "ObjectiveRecord.h"
call init method like this

(instancetype)init {

self = [super init];

if (self) {

[[CoreDataManager sharedManager] setModelName:@"YourModelName"];
}

return self; }

Hope this helps to someone...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to load a Database from a different/the wrong bundle?
For instance from or within a Framework?

I had this issue and solved it by loading the DB from the `bundle` of the related Framework. And then it all worked fine!!

Swift 4 + MagicalRecord:

```
let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: AClassFromTheFramework.self)
let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: [frameworkBundle])
MagicalRecord.setShouldAutoCreateManagedObjectModel(false)
NSManagedObjectModel.mr_setDefaultManagedObjectModel(managedObjectModel)
MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStack(withAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed: "db.sqlite")
```

And voila !

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, actually i was calling `MyEnty` instead of `MyEntity` so please re-check what names you have given to your entities and call the same and also check whether you are calling same attributes that you have defined like `name`

Answer (score 0):

- having an entity in the xcdatamodel
- using the entity for some time in the project
- later I have removed the entity from the code, but not from the xcdatamodel.
- solution: removed the unsued entity also from the xcdatamodel file

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred for me when I accidentally initialized my Core Data stack twice.